# Lucene: Multiple words in a single term

Tags: java, lucene

Let's say I have a docs like

```
stringfield:123456
textfield:name website stackoverflow
```

and If I build a query in the following manner

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
QueryParser luceneQueryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, "", analyzer);
Query luceneSearchQuery = luceneQueryParser.parse("textfield:\"name website\"");
```

it will return the doc as expected, but if I build my query using Lucene QueryAPI

```
PhraseQuery firstNameQuery  = new PhraseQuery();
    firstNameQuery.add(new Term("textfield","name website"));
```

it will not give me any result, i will have to tokenize "name website" and add each token in phrasequery.

Is there any default way in QueryAPI to tokenize as it does while parsing a String Query.
Sure I can do that myself but reinvent the wheel if it's already implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the entire query as a single term to your PhraseQuery.  You are on the right track, but when tokenized, that will not be a single term, but rather two.  That is, your index has the terms *name*, *website*, and *stackoverflow*, but your query only has one term, which matches none of those *name website*.

The correct way to use a PhraseQuery, is to add each term to the PhraseQuery separately.

```
PhraseQuery phrase = new PhraseQuery();
phrase.add(new Term("textfield", "name"));
phrase.add(new Term("textfield", "website"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you:

```
luceneQueryParser.parse("textfield:\"name website\"");
```

Lucene will tokenize the string "name website", and get 2 terms.

When you:

```
new Term("textfield","name website")
```

Lucene will not tokenize the string "name website", instead use the whole as a term.

As the result what you said, when you index the document, the field textfield MUST be Indexed and Tokenized.